# Wordpress loads styles and scripts from wrong localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, localhost

I have installed wordpress in htdocs / store folder
All the styles and scripts loads from **localhost/store/**.. location
where in my localhost works with 81 port: **localhost:81/store**

This is strange when I activate particular theme, this issue happens other default theme works fine. 
Please refer to screenshot attached.

**What I tried so far:** 
Checked the database for site and Url, all are fine.
`Appearance > general > Home` url and site url is also accurate to localhost:81/.

[image]

NOTE: my other localhost wordpress websites works fine, theme I bought may have issue. Im tired of finding solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the port to the Wordpress Address and Site Address in Dashboard -> Settings -> General.

Source: http://jumptuck.com/2009/01/09/wordpress-on-non-standard-port-not-port-80/

Comment: the links in settings are also correct still loads from wrong url.

Comment: If this happens for a particular theme only, look at the theme's `head.php` and check the code that includes the resources. It's possible the theme creator didn't use the proper path, i.e. the one from the settings.

Comment: Right the theme has issue, the function which removed port is corrected now. 
Thankx all

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the site url in wordpress general settings are right?

if yes try to change site url in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL